# mapping through all non-empty objects in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, framerjs

I'm using Framer X (which uses react) to generate a bunch of components. I have an array of objects like so:

```
const chosenBets = [{}, { id: 1
 label: "X"
 odd: 2.63
 oddIndex: 1
 team_home: "Bournemouth"
 team_away: "West Ham United"
 matchCardIndex: 1}]
```

I'm then mapping through the array:

```
        {props.chosenBets.map((match, i) => {
            return (
                <div key={i}>
                    {i}
                </div>
            )
        })}
```

The result will be generating two divs, seems the length of the array is 2. How do I make it so that only non-empty objects are rendered?

Comment: you could do `chosenBets.filter(whatever).map....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if objects are non-empty in `map`. Alternatively, use `.filter()`.

```
{props.chosenBets.map((match, i) => {
  if (Object.keys(match).length !== 0
    return (
      <div key={i}>
        {i}
      </div>
    );
})}
```

Answer (score 2):

simply use `filter` first and then `map`

```
{props.chosenBets.filter(v=> Object.keys(v).length).map((match, i) => {
       return (
       <div key={i}>
           {i}
       </div>
     )
 })}
```